# Cannot install RawTherapee from PPA on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, ppa, 18.04

Trying to install RawTherapee on Ubuntu 18.04 from a PPA.  Running `sudo apt-get install rawtherapee` gives the following error:

```
Some packages could not be installed.
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or 
if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages
have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  rawtherapee :
  Depends: topmenu-gtk3 but it is not installable
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Running the command `apt-cache policy rawtherapee` the output is:

```
rawtherapee:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 5.4-1dhor~bionic  
 Version table:
  5.4-1dhor~bionic 500
     500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dhor/myway/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
  5.3-1 500
     500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Do you know how can I solve it?

Comment: You did something wrong. On clean 18.04 LTS it installs without problems. Please add output of `apt-cache policy rawtherapee` to the question. Are you using PPAs or third-party repositories?

Comment: @N0rbert I addded the output of that command, so I suppose that the problem is apt-get tries to install from a third party repository which may be the dhor repository. Maybe I should re-compile by myself or install the version 5.3 from the ubuntu repository

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `topmenu-gtk3` does not exist in 18.04.  The problem described is likely caused by attempting to install a package compiled for 17.10.  For instance, if installing from a ppa in which old binaries were copied rather than recompiled.

The most expedient solution is to remove the offending ppa (or other nonstandard repository) and install the official packages.

One may also choose to download the source; edit `debian/control` to remove the dependency; then recompile or upload to a ppa.  This is the route I typically take, and the result may be found by [searching launchpad for rawtherapee](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=rawtherapee).  However, the problem with relying on other's ppa is you're beholden to their whims and fancies.

Comment: I think this is the problem. I added the output of the command 'apt-cache' and apparently the official ppa suggests to install the previous version of rawtherapee.